# case statement with column existence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to check the column existence addressid with case statement and if exists then my query has to return addressid .If not exists then addressname.
Executed below statement

```sql
Select case when COL_LENGTH('dbo.address', 'addressid') IS NOT NULL then addressid else  addressname end as AddressName
from dbo.address
```

but the Case statement is throwing error:

> Invalid column name 'addressid'.

How to check column existence and use the column in same query if exists.

Comment: It is highly unusual to be writing a query and not know if a column is in a table.

Comment: T-SQL is a compiled language; the statement has to be valid to it to be able to be compiled, and thus if your table, `dbo.address` doesn't have the column `addressid` the compilation fails. This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Also, `CASE` **expression**; T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: See answer here for one approach [Why can't I use a CASE statement to see if a column exists and not SELECT from it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-cant-i-use-a-case-statement-to-see-if-a-column-exists-and-not-select-from-i/66755#66755)

Answer (score 1):

> How to check column existence and use the column in same query if exists.

It is not clear to me if you really mean to check if column exists or maybe you meant to check if the column is NULL - meaning it has no value. The second option is more common and make more sense but I will assume that you did not made a mistake in the question and that you meant to check if the column exists. In this case:

Since you do not have the table structure and your query depends on it, you need to build your query dynamically. In order to executes a Transact-SQL statement has been built dynamically, you need to use the build-in stored procedure sp_executesql.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

```
-- Preparation DDL+DML
create table t1(col1 int, col3 int)
create table t2(col1 int, col2 int)
GO

insert t1 (col1, col3) values (1,2), (3,4)
insert t2 (col1, col2) values (1,2), (3,4)
GO

-- solution
DECLARE @Table2Check NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Column2CheckFirst NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Column2CheckIfNotExists NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- Solution: Test for table t1 if column col2 exists
SET @Table2Check = 't1'
SET @Column2CheckFirst = 'col2'
SET @Column2CheckIfNotExists = 'col1'
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table2Check and COLUMN_NAME = @Column2CheckFirst
)
SELECT @MyQuery = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME (@Column2CheckFirst) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME (@Table2Check)
ELSE 
SELECT @MyQuery = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME (@Column2CheckIfNotExists) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME (@Table2Check)
PRINT @MyQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you may use dynamic sql to get it to work.

```
Declare @QueryText nVarChar(max)

Select @QueryText = Concat('Select ', 
                           Case When COL_LENGTH('dbo.address', 'addressid') Is Not Null Then 'addressid' Else 'addressname' End,
                           ' as AddressName ', 'From dbo.address')

Exec sp_executesql @QueryText
```